# Silverlight: Difficulty with binding to visiblity

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have two elements: a listbox and a "this list is empty" message. I'd like to bind their visibility to the list box's `ItemsSource` being empty. However, I'm not sure how to do this:

```
        <TextBlock Text="No favorite searches yet. Add some by searching, then clicking 'Add to Favorites'" 
                   Padding="10,0" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=FavoriteFilters.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"
                   />

        <ListBox ItemsSource="FavoriteFilters" 
                 x:Name="favoriteFiltersList" 
                 Visibility="{Binding Path=FavoriteFilters.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <my:FavoriteFilterLink />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

They are both visible, although the `ItemsSource` is empty. Also, I'm not sure how to invert the condition for the `ListBox`.

The visibility converter:

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool?)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)parameter))
            {
                return (value as bool?).Value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            } else
            {
                return (value as bool?).Value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off writing two converters, one for the ListBox the other for the TextBlock. The logic of each would be simpler and you wouldn't need to pass a parameter to get the correct result.

While it might not be as elegant as a single converter solution it will be far more maintainable.

If you really want to pass a parameter then you need to use the `ConverterParameter`.

There's an example [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/Tip-How-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-value-converter.aspx) but I'm not 100% sure it'll meet your requirements. The simplified XAML syntax is:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding FavoriteFilters.IsEmpty,
     Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}"/>

<ListBox Visibility="{Binding FavoriteFilters.IsEmpty,
     Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}"/>
```

Then in your converter (simplified):

```
bool show = (bool)value;
bool visible = (bool)parameter;
if (visible)
{
    return show ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
else
{
    return show ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: How would I pass a parameter to a converter if I wanted to?

Comment: Thanks. I think the link is broken though.

Comment: @Rosarch - I removed the link as I think the information it gives in incorrect in it's details. I'm trying to find a good example (I've got some code at work, but I'm at home so I don't have access at the moment).

Comment: Ok, thanks for that example. But I'm still having trouble with the binding at all. A breakpoint in the converter method is not being hit. Is something wrong with my binding syntax?

Comment: @Rosarch - I'm not sure. It looks like it should work. It might be worth trying to bind to a different property first to get the logic working. You could either then set that property to `FavoriteFilters.IsEmpty` in the view model or try and get it working directly.